# Androidの外付けNFCの開発について

Tags: android, android-studio

Nexus7で勤怠管理のアプリを開発しました。 
しかし、NFCが背面でタッチしづらいため、外付けのNFCカードリーダーを購入しそこにタッチする方式にしようと考えています。

NFCカードリーダーはSonyPasori RC-S380を購入しようと考えています。 
しかし、下記リンク先のアプリケーション開発の項目の記述を見ると、RC-S380でAndroidアプリを開発するには専用のSDKが必要なようです。 
http://www.sony.co.jp/Products/felica/business/products/RC-S380.html#appli

そこで質問なのですが、このRC-S380をAndroidに接続した場合、今まで開発していたプログラムでは動かないのでしょうか？ 
それとも、SDKは絶対に必要ではなく、今まで開発していたプログラムでも問題なく動作するのでしょうか？

また、もし専用のSDKが必要である場合、SDKが必要ないAndroid対応の外付けのNFCカードリーダーはあるのでしょうか？

Answer (score 1):

Android の標準の API を使って開発していたのであれば、 RC-S380 では動きません。
標準 API で使える外付けのカードリーダーも知ってる限りでは存在しません。

Answer (score 0):

発想を変えて、背面にあるNFCのアンテナを前面に引き出しては如何でしょう。
多少、感度は下がるかも知れませんが、磁気結合で外部アンテナを利用するアクセサリ(NFC Patch Kit)が http://flomio.com/shop/ で販売されています。